# Order of $f(n) = 4n + 6n^3 - 8n^5$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

If a function $$f(n) = 4n + 6n^3 - 8n^5$$ then the order of $f$ is:

The answer I have is $\log(n)$, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: How did you get $\log(n)$? Also, "order" here means what precisely?

Comment: Are you sure that the answer is not $O(5)$?

Comment: "The answer I have..." means what source, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The order of a polynomial is usually its largest power. In this case, it would be 5.

If instead you are trying to find $g$ s.t.
$$
f\in O\left(g\right)\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty,
$$
(big O notation) then $g$ can be $n^{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$
be the function
$$f(n) := 4n + 6n^{3} - 8n^{5}.$$

There are two possibilities:

1) $f(n) = o(n^{6}),$
for we have
$$\frac{f(n)}{n^{6}} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty.$

2) $f(n) = O(n^{5}),$
for we have
$$\frac{f(n)}{n^{5}} < -7$$
eventually.